# SqlDataReader.GetValue in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have two columns in database

```
[Title] [Locked]
```

and Values are

```
[A] [1]  
[B] [4]   
[C] [1]
```

Let say, if I want to retrieve the data from row 2, column 2 -> Number 4 data, 
    SqlDataReader class GetValue method, in which number should be inserted?

Comment: Hi Yhal Htet Aung. Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean? I checked the API from Microsoft and it only shows the column number, so I am just wondering, whether they start to count from the 0 or 1.

Comment: I mean have you tried something to solve your problem?

Comment: Wait,

// iAssociate = (int)sdrReader.GetValue(2);

This command will retrieve the data of 1 from the first row, 2nd column (1) or it will retrieve the data "B", the second row, first column.

Comment: hiya, it's great that you've added this info, but sadly code-formatting in comments is really awful - very hard to understand. Could you please instead edit your question and add the info there? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number is [zero-based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx). So 0 will get you the first column, and 1 will get you the second.

```
var query = "SELECT title, locked FROM some_table;"

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(someConnection, query))
{
    ...  // open the connection, run the query, assign the results to yourReader

    while (yourReader.Read())
    {
        var title = (string)yourReader.GetValue(0);
        var locked = (int)yourReader.GetValue(1);

        // do something with title and locked
    }
}
```

Comment: So
A 1
B 4
C 1
 

it is like A is GetValue(0), 1 is GetValue(1)
B is GetValue(2)??

Comment: I built a data structure with ArrayList and insert into the ArrayList. Then by using function, I retrieve back the values. :)